# Sharing functions across different types

Tags: types, f#, record

We have an etl process written if f# that takes data sorted in a relational database and transforms it into a star schema ready for a 3rd party platform.  Because we are denormalization the data we have (almost) duplicate objects, types and properties scattered around our system.  Up until now I’ve been happy with this because the objects are different enough to warrant different functions or we have been able to group common/shared properties into a sub-record.

However, we are now adding objects which needs to pick and choose different parts of the system and don’t fall into existing common grouping.
After experimenting with a few different styles I’ve falling into using interfaces but something doesn’t feel right about using them.  Has anyone come across this problem and come up with a different approach?

```
module rec MyModels =
    type AccountType1 =
        { Id : int
          Error : string option 
          Name : string option }
        // PROBLEM: this get very bulky as more properties are shared
        interface Props.Error<AccountType1> with member x.Optic = (fun _ -> x.Error), (fun v -> { x with Error = v })
        interface Props.AccountId<AccountType1> with member x.Optic = (fun _ -> x.Id), (fun v -> { x with Id = v })
        interface Props.AccountName<AccountType1> with member x.Optic = (fun _ -> x.Name), (fun v -> { x with Name = v })

    type AccountType2 =
        { Id : int
          Error : string option 
          AccountId : int
          AccountName : string option
          OtherValue : string }
        interface Props.Error<AccountType2> with member x.Optic = (fun _ -> x.Error), (fun v -> { x with Error = v })
        interface Props.AccountId<AccountType2> with member x.Optic = (fun _ -> x.AccountId), (fun v -> { x with AccountId = v })
        interface Props.AccountName<AccountType2> with member x.Optic = (fun _ -> x.AccountName), (fun v -> { x with AccountName = v })
        interface Props.OtherValue<AccountType2> with member x.Optic = (fun _ -> x.OtherValue), (fun v -> { x with OtherValue = v })

    module Props =
        type OpticProp<'a,'b> = (unit -> 'a) * ('a -> 'b)    

        // Common properties my models can share
        // (I know they should start with an I)

        type Error<'a> = abstract member Optic : OpticProp<string option, 'a>
        let Error (h : Error<_>) = h.Optic

        type AccountId<'a> = abstract member Optic : OpticProp<int, 'a>
        let AccountId (h : AccountId<_>) = h.Optic

        type AccountName<'a> = abstract member Optic : OpticProp<string option, 'a>
        let AccountName (h : AccountName<_>) = h.Optic

        type OtherValue<'a> = abstract member Optic : OpticProp<string, 'a>
        let OtherValue (h : OtherValue<_>) = h.Optic

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Optics =
    // Based on Aether
    module Operators =
        let inline (^.) o optic = (optic o |> fst) ()
        let inline (^=) value optic = fun o ->  (optic o |> snd) value

    let inline get optic o =
        let get, _ = optic o
        get ()

    let inline set optic v (o : 'a) : 'a = 
        let _, set = optic o
        set v

open MyModels
open Optics.Operators

// Common functions that change the models

let error msg item =
    item
    |> (Some msg)^=Props.Error
    |> Error

let accountName item = 
    match item^.Props.AccountId with
    | 1 -> 
        item
        |> (Some "Account 1")^=Props.AccountName
        |> Ok
    | 2 -> 
        item
        |> (Some "Account 2")^=Props.AccountName
        |> Ok
    | _ ->
        item
        |> error "Can't find account"

let correctAccount item =
    match item^.Props.AccountName with
    | Some "Account 1" -> Ok item
    | _ ->
        item
        |> error "This is not Account 1"

let otherValue lookup item =
    let value = lookup ()

    item
    |> value^=Props.OtherValue
    |> Ok

// Build the transform pipeline

let inline (>=>) a b =
    fun value ->
    match a value with
    | Ok result -> b result
    | Error error -> Error error


let account1TransformPipeline lookups = // Lookups can be passed around is needed
    accountName
    >=> correctAccount

let account2TransformPipeline lookups =
    accountName
    >=> correctAccount
    >=> otherValue lookups

// Try out the pipelines

let account1 = 
    ({ Id = 1; Error = None; Name = None } : AccountType1)
    |> account1TransformPipeline ()

let account2 = 
    ({ Id = 1; Error = None; AccountId = 1; AccountName = None; OtherValue = "foo" } : AccountType2)
    |> account2TransformPipeline (fun () -> "bar")
```

Other thing’s I've tried:

- Aether Optics – Unless I’m missing something this is just for editing
  sub-types of a complex object not for common properties
- Duck typing – I quite liked this but the problem is you must inline far too 
  many function

Comment: You could take a look at [F# Crates](https://www.gresearch.co.uk/2018/08/17/squeezing-more-out-of-the-f-type-system-introducing-crates/).

Comment: I think your interfaces are fine. SRTP (duck typing) will make it worse imho.

Comment: Actually I've done something very similar...but I autogenerate most of the code

Answer (score 21):

I'm not really sure how to make your solution simpler - I think that the very fancy use of types in your approach makes the code quite complex. There may be other ways of simplifying this while keeping some kind of typing. Equally, I think there are cases where the logic you need to implement is just fairly dynamic and then it might be worth using some more dynamic techniques, even in F#.

To give an example, here is an example of doing this using the [Deedle data frame library](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/). This lets you represent data as data frames (with column names as strings).

Writing the two cleaning operations that you need over a data frame is relatively easy - the library is optimized for column-based operations, so the code structure is a bit different than yours (we calculate new column and then replace it for all rows in the data frame):

```
let correctAccount idCol nameCol df = 
  let newNames = df |> Frame.getCol idCol |> Series.map (fun _ id ->
    match id with
      | 1 -> "Account 1" 
      | 2 -> "Account 2" 
      | _ -> failwith "Cannot find account")
  df |> Frame.replaceCol nameCol newNames

let otherValue newValue df = 
  let newOther = df |> Frame.getCol "OtherValue" |> Series.mapAll (fun _ _ -> Some newValue)
  df |> Frame.replaceCol "OtherValue" newOther
```

Your pipeline can then take records, convert them to data frames and do all the processing:

```
[ { Id = 1; Error = None; Name = None } ]
|> Frame.ofRecords
|> correctAccount "Id" "Name"

[ { Id = 1; Error = None; AccountId = 1; AccountName = None; OtherValue = "foo" } ]
|> Frame.ofRecords
|> correctAccount "Id" "AccountName"
|> otherValue "bar"
```

This is less type-safe than your approach, but I believe that people can actually read the code and get a good idea of what it does, which might be worth the tradeoff.

Comment: I agree, lens' just make the code hard to read, and this isn't a partially hard problem, except it now looks like it is with all the optics...

Comment: Is deedle similar to ado.net dataset or datatable or Apache spark data frame?

Comment: Deedle is inspired by Python's pandas library and R data frames. ADO.NET dataset is probably not so close (because it does not have a lot of operations you can do on it). I don't know Spark data frames that well, but I guess they are related (but Deedle is not for big data).

Comment: Thanks Tomas for you feedback and taking the time to work up an example. The code you have produced is great for modelling the data in my question so it’s a great answer.
However, in our production system I don’t think I can lose the type-safely and add magic stings as it could lead to run time failures.  I don’t think our system classes as “big data” in the grand scheme of things but we see it as big data.

Comment: @davidtme I definitely wrote the answer just to show what a more dynamic alternative might look like - there are certainly other ways of doing this and perhaps there is even nicer and type-safe way. If I was facing the problem that was illustrated by your question, I'd probably go for a dynamic option - because enforcing safety in this case simply has too high readability cost for me. (And perhaps, I'd need a few more tests to make sure that the handling is correct, but that might be a price worth paying.)